# Have jquery and float function in html but can't get my text to wrap around my images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-float

So I have two images that I am floating left and stacking on top of each other while using a jquery click over effect. I can get the images to float left with the effect but my text is not wrapping around the images but is instead starting below the second image. I'm not sure where the issue is with the html. I appreciate the assistance.

```
<img class="floatleft"><div class="fadehover"><img src=" http://hhsidealab.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/the-people-v1-257x257-CONTRAST-1.png" alt="The People" class="b"/></div></img><img class="floatleft"><div class="fadehover"></a>

<a href=" http://hhsidealab.wpengine.com/people/"><img src=" http://hhsidealab.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/the-projects-v2-257x257-CONTRAST-V1.png" alt="The Projects" class="b"/></a></div></img>

<div id="home-text-4">The foundational effort of the IDEA Lab is to disrupt the barriers between organizational siloes and practices that prevent people from working together. 
    <p>We do this by equipping HHS Employees and members of the public with  new methodologies, aircover and pathways for innovation.</p>
    <p> We believe that people taking action on an idea is essential to the modernization of government.</p>
    <p> The IDEA Lab has engaged hundreds of people by helping them act, formulate a project  and produce results. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your css.  Also, you have a `</a>` with no `<a>`.  Unless I'm missing it.

Comment: And the javascript you're using for the stacking effect would be helpful